# Signing a string with RSA private key on Google App Engine Python SDK

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rsa

Is there any known way to sign a plain text string with RSA private key on Google App Engine Python SDK?

Comment: Just found a solution on this thread http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/ca8b1182d9ac3e5b/8780327439c3cf7a?lnk=gst&q=RSA#8780327439c3cf7a

Comment: If you want a secure implementation then you need an RSA signature scheme that uses an appropriate padding. Neither pycrypto nor the implementation on http://stuvel.eu/rsa recommended in on one of the answers do use a correct padding, and hence should not be used. Python has some bindings to good implemenations like openssl, but unfortunately I don't know what is available on Google's app engine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The library tlslite included in the gdata python library is a good option.

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/

example:

```
from tlslite.utils import keyfactory
private_key = keyfactory.parsePrivateKey(rsa_key)
signed = private_key.hashAndSign(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used it, but this appears to be a pure-Python RSA implementation, so it might work on App Engine:

http://stuvel.eu/rsa

Their [Mercurial repo](http://hg.stuvel.eu/python-rsa) appears to be fairly active, too.