# OpenSSL signing and Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cryptography, openssl

Is there a way to sign values with a PEM formatted private key in Google App Engine (Python)?

For example in PHP it could be achieved like this:

```
$key = openssl_pkey_get_private($privateKey);
openssl_sign($strToBeSigned, $signature, $key);
echo "signature: ".base64_encode($signature);
```

Is there a way to do the same thing with Python in Google App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking a look at this question's answers, and the link to the google group discussion to see if that helps.

[Signing a string with RSA private key on Google App Engine Python SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364084/signing-a-string-with-rsa-private-key-on-google-app-engine-python-sdk)

Comment: I already found out how to use tlslite for this, but thanks anyway, the answer was pointing towards the same direction