# importing m2crypto to google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, m2crypto

Hey, I'm having a bit of trouble importing m2crypto to google app engine. I think I know the problem but don't know how to fix it. Anyway, here's my directory structure.

```
mysite/
    app.yaml
    main.py
    urls.py
    ...
    M2Crypto/
        __init.py__ (I think the problem is here)
        EVP.py
        ...
    SWIG/
        (there is no __init.py___ file here)
        _m2crypto.i
        ...
```

When I do this `from M2Crypto import EVP`, I get an error message that says `<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named __m2crypto`. This error is in the `__init.py__` file where it attempts to `import __m2crypto` on line 22. But there is no `__m2crypto` file in the M2Crypto directory.

I'm using version 0.21.1 of M2Crypto and only copied M2Crypto and SWIG to my application. I've also tried copying every file in the M2Crypto-0.21.1.tar.gz to my application but that didn't work either. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you compiled the source code? It looks like it requires a shared library that must be compiled aside from the python wrapper.

Comment: I don't think so, just unzipped M2Crypto-0.21.1.tar.gz and took out the M2Crypto and SWIG directories. I've done this with another package (gdata) and that worked fine.

Comment: someone just told me in my other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776385/rsa-encryption-routines-for-google-app-engine-python/8799470#comment11036794_8799470) that m2crypto contains C code and won't work on GAE. thanks for your help though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as though m2crypto has several requirements that aren't going to work well on App Engine.  Your application is [sandboxed](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Sandbox), all of the libraries used must be pure Python.

You don't state what you're actually trying to do, but note that PyCrypto is [included with App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#PyCrypto).  You may also want to look into using the [URLFetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) service.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying to get google app engine to make signed urls for amazon cloudfront. So far, I only know of one tutorial (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549787/getting-started-with-secure-aws-cloudfront-streaming-with-python) which does it though M2Crypto.